# Error building a script for linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to build a script for linux to help me each time I install linux from scratch.
The Script have to 1.- Add repositories 2.- Install software from those repositories.

Adding repositories are not the problem, the problem is when i try to install software from this repo.
For the Repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
```

After that, the script should make an update, so:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It looks simple, but is not, because I receive an error:

The command *Update* could not be found. 
And so on the rest of the softwares

```
apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer
```

The package oracle-java8-installer couldn't be found..

I really don't know what should I do, nothing looks to work, I gave full rigths to the file and so on... always the same error.
But if I run the command apt-get install direct from the terminal, works without problem..

Any help?

Comment: There is at least on (set of?) script to build LFS https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=build+LFS+automatically

Comment: dos2unix solved the problem...

Comment: @Emal011 You should write up an answer to this question and accept it

Comment: No, please don't write up an answer that `dos2unix` solved your problem. There are already 1000s of Q/As here the mention `dos2unix`, but I realize that newbies shouldn't be expected to know how to compose a Q that will automatically lead to a `dos2unix` answer. ;-/ . @Emal011 better to delete this Q, as it will not really help future readers. Glad you got your problem resolved, but be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info for the low hanging fruit of shell errors. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

actually I wrote a script in windows to use it in future Linux installations, for some reasons it doesn't work as I want it. Thinking it was a command or misspelled words, I search for a solution, wich didn't help anyways.

Debugging my script in a virtual Machine, I found that the script was giving some random errors like '/r' doesn't support and like that. Really weird because after searching in my script for that line code I didn't find it.

With that in mind, I search again for those errors, and found that for some reasons, if you write your code in a Windows maschine, it save it in a crlf type, wich in a Linux system is interpreted really wrong.

A solution of some users was converting the type from CRLF to LF, wich in linux is using the command *dos2unix*.

```
dos2unix filename.sh
```

After making that and runing my script again everything works perfectly.